# Importing and using vanila JS functions in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draw.io

I am very new to react.js and JavaScript, so apologies in advance. I'm trying to integrate https://diagrams.net into other webpage using the file that's directly given by diagrams.net here:

https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-integration/blob/master/diagram-editor.js?fbclid=IwAR1FMViVLW3Tba8RqMOUJtv16vIvPPycLYyu4rEtRTbuhbyztlrLXu5UyHo.

So as it can be seen in this example here: http://jgraph.github.io/drawio-integration/javascript.html, when the user double clicks on the diagram, they should be redirected to diagrams.net web and draw their own diagram.

The problem is that my web is currently built on React, and all the diagrams.net is built on vanilla JS. By inspecting the example above, they apparently use:

```
<img 
style="cursor:pointer;" 
title="Click to edit image" 
onclick="DiagramEditor.editElement(this);" 
src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0...
```

in the HTML to display the image of the diagram. I've tried to change it to react-like by changing it to:

```
<img alt="Click to edit image" 
onClick={EditDiagram.DiagramEditor.editElement(this)}
src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0..."/>
```

and importing the JavaScript file by `import * as EditDiagram from "../components/workarea/workarea-diagram-editor";`, but it is returning `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'editElement')`.

I've also tried using dangerouslySetInnerHTML like this:

```
<div
dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
__html:
"<img style='cursor:pointer;' 
title='Click to edit image' onclick='DiagramEditor.editElement(this);' 
src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0...'/>",
}}/>
```

but this way, that `DiagramEditor.editElement(this)` cannot be accessed that way.

I've been trying to get this to work for past 12 hours, but just can't get it to work. Is there any way to make this work?

Thank you so much.

Below is the React code that the JavaScript is being added on.

```
const WorkArea = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      scenario: "This is scenario",
    },
    validationSchema: Yup.object({
      scenario: Yup.string().max(255).required("Scenario is required"),
    }),
    onSubmit: () => {
      router.push("/");
    },
  });

  const [countList, setCountList] = useState([0]);
  //   const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([]);

  const AddScenario = () => {
    let countArr = [...countList];
    let counter = countArr.slice(-1)[0];
    counter++;
    countArr.push(counter);
    setCountList(countArr);
  };

  const DeleteScenario = () => {
    let countArr = [...countList];
    let counter = countArr.slice(-1)[0];
    counter--;
    countArr.pop(counter);
    setCountList(countArr);
  };

  //   const onAddBtnClick = (event) => {
  //     setInputList(inputList.concat(<SetScenario key={inputList.length} />));
  //   };

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Work Area | Cybersecurity Requirements Generator</title>
      </Head>
      <Box
        component="main"
        sx={{
          alignItems: "center",
          display: "flex",
          flexGrow: 1,
          minHeight: "100%",
        }}
      >
        <Container maxWidth="xl">
          <NextLink href="/projects" passHref>
            <Button component="a" startIcon={<ArrowBackIcon fontSize="small" />}>
              Back to Projects
            </Button>
          </NextLink>
          <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
            <Box sx={{ my: 3 }}>
              <Typography color="textPrimary" variant="h4">
                Use Case Diagram
              </Typography>
              <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom variant="body2">
                Make your own diagram!
              </Typography>
            </Box>

            <Box
              sx={{
                py: 2,
              }}
            >
              {/* <div
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                  __html:
                    "<img style='cursor:pointer;' title='Click to edit image' onclick='DiagramEditor.editElement(this);' src='data:image/png;base64,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'/>",
                }}
              /> */}

              <img
                alt="Click to edit image"
                onClick={EditDiagram.DiagramEditor.editElement(this)}
                src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAHkAAAA9CAYAAACJM8YzAAADT3RFWHRteGZpbGUAJTNDbXhmaWxlJTIwaG9zdCUzRCUyMmVtYmVkLmRpYWdyYW1zLm5ldCUyMiUyMG1vZGlmaWVkJTNEJTIyMjAyMS0wMS0xMVQxMCUzQTQxJTNBMzQuMjQ4WiUyMiUyMGFnZW50JTNEJTIyNS4wJTIwKE1hY2ludG9zaCUzQiUyMEludGVsJTIwTWFjJTIwT1MlMjBYJTIwMTFfMV8wKSUyMEFwcGxlV2ViS2l0JTJGNTM3LjM2JTIwKEtIVE1MJTJDJTIwbGlrZSUyMEdlY2tvKSUyMENocm9tZSUyRjg3LjAuNDI4MC44OCUyMFNhZmFyaSUyRjUzNy4zNiUyMiUyMGV0YWclM0QlMjJtNXI1QVhFdDE3eWx2WWlEWXo5UyUyMiUyMHZlcnNpb24lM0QlMjIxNC4xLjklMjIlMjB0eXBlJTNEJTIyZW1iZWQlMjIlM0UlM0NkaWFncmFtJTIwaWQlM0QlMjJlbVlSU0REUmtEUDJZZDNFWnkzciUyMiUyMG5hbWUlM0QlMjJQYWdlLTElMjIlM0VqWkxOVG9Rd0VJQ2ZwbGV6MEloNkZkZjE0Z2tUejVXT3ROblNrbElXOE9sdDdWUm9OaVplWU9hYjZmd1RXdmZMeWJKQnZCb09pcFFIdmhENlJNcXlxS283JTJGd3RramVTV1BrVFFXY2tqT215Z2tWJTJCQUx4T2RKSWNSV1VUT0dPWGtrTVBXYUEydHl4aXoxc3k1MjZkUmVkYUJkWkI1Qk5DMFRGM1RkOG1kaVBTJTJCckRiJTJCQXJJVEtYTlJZWDhmckQxMzFrd2E4Mm1qSVZwNmxzSmdEYU5nM013N1JJJTJCRTF0WVlGNlYlMkJxVUdGc2VZVGUlMkY3RGlpV1BiazFOcEZvdGFQZXZDS21KQzFNVHhuZ1RjZ3d1NGNQQ0ZtQjBOMWVaWmlFZE5BTnJnejc3a3lEMFViaGVlYTN3NG5VaFdPd0ZySU5saDdDd0U1Z2VuRjI5QzFyVDBOWmNuYmZsRkltSjNXSXFaQXp2b2ZzTnZNM0JDemlLcEc0NyUyQkxIdGJwd2V2d0UlM0QlM0MlMkZkaWFncmFtJTNFJTNDJTJGbXhmaWxlJTNFoE8CRAAABV1JREFUeF7tm1lIlVsYht+NXoSipGkIGpoDBYqiKIIQSCiRSigOCV2odZuSw51KoYaR8xCkGDmiaCDiVM5JSQiKoSiFaVk5UoKK4nz4Fmd73KmdvZX28ez1rZst7rXW/7/vs961vl/8FQB2wU2nHVAQ5J2dHZ0WKbM4PT29XQF5d5fDrIsLgbgyZF0ku08TQ9ZxwCSPITNkCRyQQCInmSFL4IAEEjnJDFkCBySQyElmyBI4IIFETjJDlsABCSRykhmyBA5IIJGTzJAlcEACiZxkhiyBAxJI5CQzZAkckEAiJ5khS+CABBJPTZLpRra3t6Gvry+B7dqVqDXI379/h5WV1ZHq2tvbERUVha9fvx7o8+DBA3z+/BmlpaVquaNpf7UmBfDlyxf09/cjNDRU3SEq/U46/lgX1eZ/a1JK5+bmxH2+f/8efn5+4tPMzEz8bnR09EjIk5OTWF9fx+XLl9XSqWl/tSYF0NjYiHv37uHTp0/qDlHpd9Lxx7qoNiHvv8GBgQG4u7tjfn4e5ubm4quOjg7cunULd+7cQUVFBc6fP4+ioiLR79mzZ5idnUViYiLq6+uRn58PmiMwMBCFhYUwNjZW0a9pfxqcnp6OyspKbG1twd/fHxkZGfTWwd68tHB8fHwwMTGB4OBgvHjxQqQ6ISEBHz58wLVr15CTk4Nz585hcXERtJvU1NSIRfzo0SM4OTkdGH9caJqO09p2rQ5kX19fBAUF4fbt28Iwejeru7sb9+/fB5mcnZ0tFkVtbS1MTEwQHx+PiIgIxMXFqejWtP/w8LAAUFxcLOal7fjp06fiXpRtdXUVeXl5yM3NRWtrKywtLWFhYYHo6GiEhITg8ePHWFpaQm9vLzIzM8WiffjwIV6+fImkpCT8/PlTzKkc7+bmpimrY/c/dZBXVlZgaGgojLx586YwTgktLS0N1tbWKCgoQGRkpDBubW0Nly5dOhSyuv3HxsZE+jw9PfHt2zcBmdJM193f9m+3BCsrKwtTU1NQKBQizXSczMzMIDU1Fe/evUNZWRkcHR3x9u1bENTOzs4TbffHpXyqINN2rTy337x5gytXrohXPJSQy8vLhbG0RVIjEJR4BweHQyGr25+KPToK6JgwMjISc9Eu8TvIlGA6Kn5ttCucPXsW4eHhAq6trS1iY2Nx9+7dE5/pOgF5f3V9GGQCSom7cOEC+vr6BAT6uaqq6lDI6vYnCJQ8OkNppwgLCxMJ/B3k5ORkvHr1Cj09PeLam5ubGBkZgYeHBz5+/IiLFy/ix48faGhoQExMjCgsx8fHOcn/BpkqW29vbwwNDYmEEAQqwJqamg6FrG7/gIAAAYWOgcHBQXENGpuSkqIyb3Nzs6gX6HGwq6tLFFuvX78WYKlQe/LkifiOzmhnZ2fQQlheXhbFGM07PT29N54mpp3gxo0bQsufbKdqu/4dZHrGpOdkSlldXZ2ovmlbfP78Oby8vA5A1qR/W1ubAEONCjt6vCMAtJhcXFz25iZIrq6u4rp0BtOWTsUgNbqf6upqXL16VRSL9Knc+umeS0pKBGTleJrbwMAALS0tuH79+p9k/P98q5EAbmxsHDiLj3JKnf70HE4QbGxsRCG1sLAAU1NTlccomp8esajYUwKkflRH2Nvb48yZM3u3QAUj/QHHzs5OFJLK9uv4P0r378n/kyRrQxhf4x8HGLIEq4EhM2QJHJBAIieZIUvggAQSOckMWQIHJJDISWbIEjgggUROMkOWwAEJJHKSGbIEDkggkZPMkCVwQAKJnGSGLIEDEkjkJDNkCRyQQCInmSFL4IAEEjnJDFkCBySQqJJkCfRKK1GhUOz+BbaftLWDFNYjAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
              />

              {/* <Tester /> */}
            </Box>
            <Box sx={{ my: 3 }}>
              <Typography color="textPrimary" variant="h4">
                Scenario
              </Typography>
              <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom variant="body2">
                Enter scenarios
              </Typography>
            </Box>

            <SetScenario countList={countList} />
            <Box
              sx={{
                alignItems: "center",
                display: "flex",
                ml: -1,
              }}
            ></Box>
            {Boolean(formik.touched.policy && formik.errors.policy) && (
              <FormHelperText error>{formik.errors.policy}</FormHelperText>
            )}
            <Box
              sx={{
                py: 2,
                display: "flex",
                justifyContent: "flex-end",
                justifyContent: "space-between",
              }}
            >
              <Box>
                <Button
                  color="primary"
                  disabled={formik.isSubmitting}
                  size="large"
                  variant="contained"
                  onClick={AddScenario}
                  sx={{
                    marginRight: 1,
                  }}
                >
                  Add Row
                </Button>
                <Button
                  color="primary"
                  disabled={formik.isSubmitting}
                  size="large"
                  variant="contained"
                  onClick={DeleteScenario}
                >
                  Delete Row
                </Button>
              </Box>

              <NextLink href="/requirements" passHref>
                <Button
                  color="primary"
                  disabled={formik.isSubmitting}
                  size="large"
                  type="submit"
                  variant="contained"
                >
                  Submit
                </Button>
              </NextLink>
            </Box>
          </form>
        </Container>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};

WorkArea.getLayout = (page) => <DashboardLayout>{page}</DashboardLayout>;
export default WorkArea;
```

Comment: try this, onClick={ () => EditDiagram.DiagramEditor.editElement(this) }

Comment: @Immanuel With that line, it does show the image but the click still doesn't work. Thanks for the help though!